# AWS CodeDeploy Command Not Found

Tags: bash, amazon-web-services, aws-code-deploy

When trying to deploy a Node.js application I'm getting an error `npm: command not found` in my `post_install.sh` AfterInstall script. What's super strange is in my BeforeInstall script I run `npm install -g pm2` and it works perfectly fine without any errors.

Both are being run as the `ubuntu` user. Why would this command work in one CodeDeploy script and fail in another?

Comment: Add the full path tot the npm executable.

Comment: @RamanSailopal How can I find that? And why exactly do I have to do that?

Comment: Type "whereis npm" at the command line and then in the script, add the full path as opposed to just npm.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Looks like I was able to solve this by adding the following to my script files.

```
export NVM_DIR="$HOME/.nvm"
[ -s "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh" ] && \. "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh"  # This loads nvm
[ -s "$NVM_DIR/bash_completion" ] && \. "$NVM_DIR/bash_completion"  # This loads nvm bash_completion
```

Hopefully this can help someone.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same problem trying to invoke the aws cli in my shell script during the `AfterInstall` hook, in an ubuntu server with ubuntu user.

This is what happened when I executed my script manually `sh ecr-login.sh`:

```sh
# Works
$(aws ecr get-login --no-include-email --region sa-east-1)

# Works
$(/home/ubuntu/.local/bin/aws ecr get-login --no-include-email --region sa-east-1)
```

When CodeDeploy executed it:

```sh
# Not Work
$(aws ecr get-login --no-include-email --region sa-east-1)

# Works
$(/home/ubuntu/.local/bin/aws ecr get-login --no-include-email --region sa-east-1)
```

Answer (score 0):

I got the same problem trying to invoke the aws cli in my shell script during the After Install hook, in an ubuntu20 server with ubuntu user.

I have checked inside /usr/bin/ folder on server yarn/pm2/node are running are not  If not run below command
root@ip-:/# ln -s /root/.nvm/versions/node/v16.17.0/bin/node /usr/bin/
root@ip-:/# ln -s /root/.nvm/versions/node/v16.17.0/bin/pm2 /usr/bin/
root@ip-:/# ln -s /root/.nvm/versions/node/v16.17.0/bin/yarn /usr/bin/

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).