# AWS CodeDeploy [stderr]/usr/bin/env: node: No such file or directory

Tags: bash, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-code-deploy

When trying to run a script on `AfterInstall` event I receive:

```sh
LifecycleEvent - AfterInstall
Script - deploy/install_dependencies.sh
[stdout]Install dependencies. /
[stderr]/usr/bin/env: node: No such file or directory
```

, which is strange because:

1. `which node` yields: `~/.nvm/versions/node/v15.2.0/bin/node`
2. `which npm` yields: `~/.nvm/versions/node/v15.2.0/bin/npm`

The *appspec.yml* wasn't setup by me, but I think it's straightforward:

```yaml
version: 0.0
os: linux
files:
  - source: /
    destination: /home/ec2-user/deploy/
permissions:
  - object: /
    pattern: "**"
    owner: ec2-user
hooks:
  AfterInstall:
    - location: deploy/install_dependencies.sh
    - location: deploy/build.sh
    - location: deploy/install_prd_dependencies.sh
    - location: deploy/copy_overwrite.sh
    # - location: deploy/migrations.sh
      timeout: 300
      runas: ec2-user
  ApplicationStart:
    - location: deploy/start_server.sh
      timeout: 300
      runas: ec2-user
```

I added `runas: ec2-user` and the `permissions` key with its values after reading this: [Start Node Application in AfterInstall Hook](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=242602)
, though not the same issue, it seemed that would solve my problem, but it didn't.

I checked if `nvm` was installed issuing `which nvm`, it didn't work:

```sh
[ec2-user@my-ip ~]$ which nvm
/usr/bin/which: no nvm in (/home/ec2-user/.nvm/versions/node/v15.2.0/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/sbin:/home/ec2-user/.local/bin:/home/ec2-user/bin)
```

but, issuing only `nvm` I recevie `nvm`'s CLI help commands without any problem.

I checked the `.bashrc` of `ec2-user` to see if nvm was being exported correctly (as suggested in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46086504/7443903)):

```sh
# User specific aliases and functions

export NVM_DIR="$HOME/.nvm"
[ -s "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh" ] && \. "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh"  # This loads nvm
[ -s "$NVM_DIR/bash_completion" ] && \. "$NVM_DIR/bash_completion"  # This loads nvm bash_completion
```

All scripts are using absolute path for npm/node binaries, examples:

install_dependencies.sh

```sh
#!/bin/bash

echo "Install dependencies. $(pwd)"
cd /home/ec2-user/deploy/

/home/ec2-user/.nvm/versions/node/v15.2.0/bin/npm install
```

start_server.sh

```sh
#!/bin/bash

echo "Restarting servers..."

/home/ec2-user/.nvm/versions/node/v15.2.0/bin/pm2 restart 0
```

Is codedpeloy using `root` user to issue these commands, even with `runas` setup for `ec2-user`? I don't understand what's happening, it worked before.

Answer (score 1):

This boils down to the path to node not available at the time of execution. If node is installed via nvm, try adding proper path.

Another way to do it is to add `source ~/.nvm/nvm.sh` to your bash profile (or an appropriate file, depending on your environment). See [Node Version Manager install - nvm command not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16904658/node-version-manager-install-nvm-command-not-found)

Answer (score 1):

TO Expand on Devin's answer, I added

```
source ~/.nvm/nvm.sh
```

to the beginning of my after_install.sh file and it did the trick.

This added the correct path to PM2 & NVM to the deployment user's path.  You can confirm this by calling the following before and after the source command:

```
echo "$PATH"
```

Answer (score 0):

I found that although CodeDeploy was running as the non-root user that I had set, it was not using the same environment variables as that user or that root was using on the command line. Try adding these lines into your script to debug:

```
echo `env`
echo `whoami`
```

I still don't know why that is. What I did was to export the path I needed before calling `npm install` in the script:

```
export PATH=$PATH:/correct/path
```